# Getting "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'proyecto_tfg.data' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `data` "

Tags: laravel

I´m encountering a curious problem. I have this function in my controller in laravel:

```
public function postData(Request $request){
        $datos=$request->all();
        $datos1=json_encode($datos);

        Log::info('Request:'.$datos1);
        $datos1Array = json_decode($datos1, true);
        
        Datum::create([
            'configuration_id' => $datos1Array['configuracion_id'],
            'student_id' => $datos1Array['student_id'],
            'puntuacion' => $datos1Array['puntuacion'],
        ]);

        return $request->all();
        
    }
```

This is supposed to create a new register in my table "Datum", but when that is executed I get the error saying that new data can´t be inserted in the table because "Data" table doesn´t exist. And the thing is that of course it doesn´t exist, because in my function I´m creating a new register in "Datum" table that does exist.
I have no clue about what could be going wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: You're using the _model_ Datum here, not a table. Did you tell your model which table to use? (If you didn't, Laravel assumes its table is called data) Can you post your model? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#table-names might be worth a read

Comment: Thank you @brombeer I read that and what I was missing in my model was this: protected $table = 'Datum';